# Extracting email domain name from whole email address

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, text-extraction

I want to extract domain name from the whole email address as shown on pictures below.

Do you know how I should do it by using VBA?

[image]

Comment: Put some more light on issue

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use VBA for this, but you can if you would like to use more advanced features such as regular expression. You have not provided any requirements so I will assume the simple case of `a@b.c`.  If the format has subdomains, such as `a@b.c.d`, it will return the subdomain rather than the domain.

You may simply use this formula in cell `C4` and drag down as necessary.

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(B4,LEN(B4)-FIND("@",B4)),FIND(".",RIGHT(B4,LEN(B4)-FIND("@",B4)))-1)
```

You could use this in VBA as the cell formula if a VBA solution is required.

Comment: Here is another formula that will work. A bit simpler I guess : `=MID(B4;SEARCH("@";B4;1)+1;SEARCH(".";B4;1)-SEARCH("@";B4;1)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

*For VBA*

```
Name = Mid$(EmailAddress, InStrRev(EmailAddress, "@") + 1, _
                                    InStrRev(EmailAddress, ".") - _
                                    InStrRev(EmailAddress, "@") - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the domain server name from an email address, try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",B4)),"",MID(B4,FIND("@",B4)+1,FIND(".",B4,FIND("@",B4))-FIND("@",B4)-1))
```